# remove any key value that is equal to the string "world" in an instance of LinkedHashMap, using for-each loop and Map.Entry(), but always get error

Tags: java, dictionary

I tried to go over an instance of LinkedHashMap and remove any key value that is equal to the string "world", using for-each loop and Map.Entry(). However, the IDE always output an error message. Could someone give me a hint as to why is this happening? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Map<String, Integer> msi1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

msi1.put("hello", 1);
msi1.put("world", 2);
msi1.put("morning", 3);

for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : msi1.entrySet()){

    if(e.getKey().equals("world")){

        msi1.remove(e.getKey());
    }
}

System.out.println(msi1);
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:711)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:744)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742)
    at JTOCollection.MapInterfaceClass2.main(MapInterfaceClass2.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: a foreach loop does internally use an `Iterator`. With it´s help you are looping over the `Map`. But if you modify the `Map` within a foreach then you´ll hit a `ConcurrentModificationException`. But why would you loop over the map, you simple have to check if a key with `world` exists and remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't remove elements from a `Map` while iterating over it with the enhanced for loop.

You can remove elements from the key `Set` (or entry `Set`) if you iterate over them with an explicit `Iterator` and use the `Iterator`'s `remove()` method.

However, the entire loop is not necesarry and can be replaced by :

```
msi1.remove("world");
```

The whole idea of a `Map` is being able to locate and remove an entry by its key efficiently without having to iterate over the entire `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationException occurs when you try to update the map in the same loop which is iterating on that map. In your code snippet you are iterating on map msi1 and updating the same by removing the key in the same loop. 
you can resolve it like below :

```
Map<String, Integer> msi1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

msi1.put("hello", 1);
msi1.put("world", 2);
msi1.put("morning", 3);

Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> set = msi1.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : set){

if(e.getKey().equals("world")){

    msi1.remove(e.getKey());
}
}

System.out.println(msi1);
```